# How to reduce border-bottom width form one side in html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

Actually I have to show bottom bar to currently active page. I am using ternary operator in PHP . The bottom bar is showing up but its horizontal width is a bit extra . I'm not been able to reduce its width . Here's a picture of it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mWRJ.png

Here's ternary operator I used:

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 ms-auto mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="{{'/' == request()->path() ? 'nav-item' : ''}}">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{route('home')}}">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="{{'novels' == request()->path() ? 'nav-item' : ''}}">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{route('novels')}}">Novels</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="{{'about' == request()->path() ? 'nav-item' : ''}}">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{route('about-us')}}">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="{{'contact' == request()->path() ? 'nav-item' : ''}}">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{route('contact-us')}}">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Here's the css:

```
 .nav-item {
    border-bottom:3px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
   margin-bottom: 19px;
   }
```

Comment: Hi, there are 2 answers for your question. But you did not react till now. Please check the answers and mark one of them as accepted if it is the case.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the problem is not in the PHP (rather Smarty or Blade template engine) logic. The problem is in your CSS definition. You set border of your `<li>` items.

**Proposed solution**

Please use the css class `nav-item` for all your `<li>` in your navbar section. Because all of these `<li>` elements in your navbar describe an navigation item independent on the fact that, whether the current page equals one of them or not.

Use rather an additional class like `current` for marking the navigation item of actual page. I did it for you.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 ms-auto mb-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item {{'/' == request()->path() ? 'current' : ''}}">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{route('home')}}">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item {{'novels' == request()->path() ? 'current' : ''}}">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{route('novels')}}">Novels</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item {{'about' == request()->path() ? 'current' : ''}}">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{route('about-us')}}">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item {{'contact' == request()->path() ? 'current' : ''}}">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{route('contact-us')}}">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then you should use the following CSS definition:

```css
.nav-item.current a.nav-link{
    border-bottom:3px black solid;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Please `upvote` and `accept` this answer, if it solves your problem.

Here is a screenshot of my solution:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to read or test your code.
We may require the code where you declared the space between your `nav-item (li)`; however, if the space between is caused by `padding-right`, then change it to `margin-right`, or get that look from flex `gap`; it should work.

```
//no changes needed in this code
 .nav-item {
    border-bottom:3px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
   margin-bottom: 19px;
   }
```